# Can we fit an 11 speed cassette to new Shimano XTR 12 speed hub?

Tags: cassette, compatibility, freehub

I'm looking for a very silent hub. Upon searching, I came across with Onyx hubs which definitely has no sound. I really like it, but my budget doesn't. So I've searched a little more and found Shimano's new 12 speed XTR hub with Scylence tech which cost half the price compared with Onyx. My problem is, it's 12 speed with new Microspline freehub body. I have an old XTR 11 speed setup.

So there lies my question, can I fit an 11 speed cassette to a XTR 12 speed hub?

I know there's a spacer but I only see an upgrade from lower speed to higher like 11 speed to 12 speed not downgrade 12 to 11.

Comment: shimano was originally planning on making microspline 11-spd cassettes. not sure if that ever happened

Comment: So for now, is there anything we can do to fit 11 speed cassette on it?

Comment: seems like a spacer would do the trick

Comment: @PaulH Shimano Hyperglide and Microspline spline size and patterns are different and incompatible. The Microspline freehub body was introduced by Shimano to allow a 10 tooth small sprocket

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus yeah, I know

Comment: FWIW, most non-Dura Ace Shimano hubs are pretty dang quiet. It's hard to image my Ultegra hubs being any quieter. So any HG-bodied hub should fit the bill. Or upgrade to 12 speed, which would be awesome.

Comment: @PaulH do you have a link to where we can order a spacer for 12 speed to 11 speed?

Comment: How did you get on in the end as I am looking at buying someone's wheels but they have a 12 speed casette and I am currently using an 11 speed SLX set up?

Comment: All hubs are silent during normal usage.  Its only when you stop pedalling that they make noise.   So, don't coast.   Instead, practice soft-pedalling where you're not putting in much power at all.

Comment: @Criggie "So, don't coast." Unfortunately, this advice does not apply to mountain biking, especially when jumps are involved. Pedaling when one is in air is not very wise, as one should instead pay attention to positioning feet for landing. Even without jumps involved, technical descends often discourage pedaling, as one can clip a rock with foot when rolling off a ledge, not to say that weight distribution is better controlled when standing on both pedals, not on one currently being pressed for spinning. Same reasoning applies to sharp turns, as my damaged right heel may witness.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov it was a slightly facetious comment, going for humour value :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to exist 11-speed microspline cassettes, meaning you can have a 11-speed drivetrain with a silent Shimano microspline hub. For example, here is a description I found at one [webshop](https://www.rosebikes.se/shimano-2669181-2669181):

> The special version of the XTR cassette is based on the 12-speed version with 10-51 teeth, but comes without the largest sprocket to offer enough space for the Wide Flange Shimano XTR FH-M9125-B rear hub (product code: 2278419) and thus for more stable wheels. <...> You even don’t need a special chain or a special shifting system, as the 9100 series shifters can be easily converted from 11 to 12-speed thanks to the Mode Converter. <...>
>
> Details:
>
> • Hyperglide+ cassette 11-speed
>
> • For singlespeed and double chainring systems
>
> • Can be integrated into a compatible 12-speed XTR system
>
> • For Shimano Micro Spline freehub
>
> • Compatible with Shimano 12-speed HG+ chains, such as Shimano CN-M9100 (product code 2273556)
>
> • Material: steel, titanium, aluminium
>
> • Aluminium spider (anodised)
>
> • Incl. aluminium locknut
>
> • Weight: approx. 299 g
>
> Gear ratio: Shimano XTR 11-speed 10-45: 10-12-14-16-18-21-24-28-33-39-45 teeth
>
> ATTENTION: Even though it is especially developed for the Shimano XTR FH-M9125-B Wide Flange rear hub, the XTR CS-M9110 11-speed cassette can also be mounted on standard XTR 12-speed hubs – losing the advantage of more stable wheels thanks to a wider hub flange.
>
> ATTENTION: Only compatible with Shimano Micro Spline freehub. Not compatible with current M900 components and other Shimano 11-speed groups.

So the answer to your title question is "yes". I am unsure from the description if you'll have to replace the shifter and/or derailleur as well in terms of how much the new cassette is compatible with older XTR derailleur indexing steps.